# ASP.net change image after DropDownList.OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following 2 elements:
DropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropPoke1" Width="80" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropPoke1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Test</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">asd</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">FF</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Image

```
<asp:Image ID="imgPoke1" Height="80" Width="80" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Images/orderedList0.png"/>
```

In the codebehind, I want to change the image:

```
protected void DropPoke1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgPoke1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/HomePicture.png";
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You should implement events handing in client code implemeted in JavaScript

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I don't have time to learn JavaScript. It should work this way as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: before you choose any item, is image displayed on the page?

Comment: @Khazratbek Well, I've predefined ImageUrl="../Images/orderedList0.png" and that works, but when I try to change it later through the change event, it stays the old picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do next:

Your design page:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropPoke1" Width="80" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropPoke1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Test</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">asd</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">FF</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Image ID="imgPoke1" Height="80" Width="80" runat="server" />
```

Your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(!IsPostBack)
        imgPoke1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/orderedList0.png";
}

protected void DropPoke1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgPoke1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/HomePicture.png";
}
```

Comment: That somehow worked, but now I have the problem of caching. If I now change that orderedList0.png to another one, the old one stays. How do I "refresh" the page correctly?

Comment: I think one thing that you need is trying to restart application. Or page, at least.

Comment: Is it web-site or web-application?

Comment: It is a web-application. Do I have to restart the application everytime?

Comment: Application build your application into one dll, so usually it keeps everything as it was in a debug time

Comment: Okay, thank you. Well, my original problem was solved, so I marked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Kohnarik You are welcome. If you need any help, just let me know and I will try to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take you up on that offer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using updatepanel? If yes, put image control inside the updatepanel.